# How to get data count for last three months as separate in single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get count of all assessments in past three months. So this should count for current and previous two months as separate

like Count1 50 for this month
     Count2 100 for one month back
     Count2 50 for two month back

```
SELECT Count(AssessmentID)
from AssessmentListing
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`AssessmentSubmittedDatetime`, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') >= 
          DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y' ))
```

Comment: Add a group by. Use month().

Comment: @jarlh can you please explain you are saying to add group by on Month I do not have Month column

Comment: And I don't know MySQL that well. Somehow you need to extract the month part from the AssessmentSubmittedDatetime column.

Comment: @jarlh you can write in sql

Comment: `AssessmentSubmittedDatetime` is date time?

Comment: @Sachu yes it is like 04-Apr-2016 02:48 PM

Comment: @DilshadAli the datatype is datetime?

Comment: @Sachu datatype is VARCHAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be storing dates as strings.  If you want the current month and two months back, then something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`AssessmentSubmittedDatetime`, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p'), '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       Count(*)
from AssessmentListing
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`AssessmentSubmittedDatetime`, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 - DAY(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
GROUP BY yyyymm;
```

I am not sure what your `WHERE` clause actually does.  But comparing a string and a date is probably not what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jarlh mentioned in comment you can use Extract function to extract the month from the date column and group the result using that.

```
select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM AssessmentSubmittedDatetime) as _month,
       Count(AssessmentID)
from AssessmentListing
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`AssessmentSubmittedDatetime`, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') >= 
          DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y' ))
group by _month
```

Comment: but this does not show separate for all it shows combined count

Comment: @DilshadAli whats the value coming in _month?

Comment: if the date value column is not date time datatype you need to convert it

Comment: any alternate to do this as Changing data type will change other things also and will effect many things which I am using

Comment: @DilshadAli convert the value to date before extracting the month

Comment: Convert in php or convert using sql

Comment: @DilshadAli convert in the query

Comment: can you please share some example ?